# Explain this behavior using PWM to control a fan

Tags: pwm, noise, fan

I bought a fan designed to exhaust attic spaces. It's a [12" fan that came with a 50 watt solar panel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FIHM92G). In full sunlight, I thought it was blowing a bit hard for my liking, so I bought a [PWM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071NQ5G71) speed controller to control the fan speed. The particular one I bought supposedly operates at a frequency of 15 kHz. However, there's an audible sound at a much lower pitch depending on how I adjust the pot. Speaking of pot, that brings me to my real question.

With the pot dialed all the way counterclockwise, the fan stops. That's expected. As I rotate the pot clockwise, the fan speeds up. It achieves maximum speed when the pot is about in the middle position. When I rotate it clockwise some more, the fan slows down.

Meanwhile, voltage at the input is 19V+ when the pot is at counterclockwisemost position. Voltage at output is very low, unsurprisingly. At maximum fan speed (at the time I took readings) input voltage was around 13V, and output voltage around 8V. If I rotated the pot clockwise from that position, input voltage and output voltage both decreased. That is what's surprising to me. It seems to me that input voltage should decrease because the load is increasing, but I'd expect the output voltage to increase, since more time at full voltage is included in each cycle, or so I thought.

If it helps, I can provide links to what I ordered.

I'm also wondering why there was an audible noise when the pot was dialed mostly clockwise. Some sort of harmonic I suppose.

Edit: I thought dialing the pot all the way clockwise would be equivalent to not having the PWM at all, but that obviously is not the case.

Comment: You didn't buy a PWM.  You _probably_ bought something called a PWM drive.  Please *edit your question* to include a link to it.  With electronics as complex as a PWM drive, you can't always expect simple behavior -- especially if you're just buying some cheap thing off eBay or Amazon.

Comment: Edited - it's called a PWM speed controller. I kept the subject line terse to not be overly wordy. Also added a link to the fan, although the model I actually got is a newer version with curved blades. That is irrelevant to this post, though.

Comment: The speed controller is severely under-documented.  Even though you may feel like you're being nibbled to death, could you measure the fan voltage and current when running straight from the solar panel, then the voltages *and currents* when running through the PWM?  It sounds like you're pulling the solar panel voltage down, and you may be pulling it low enough that the speed controller stops working.

Comment: It is possible that the fan is brushless. If so, the fan's built-in electronic circuit may not be particularly happy with PWM input. The PWM controller is apparently designed for 7-70 VDC input. The optimum operating voltage may be higher than the 12 V optimum operating point of the solar panel and fan combination. This is a question about hooking two products together and getting them to work together. Since that is not an electrical engineering design or theory question, I am voting to close.

Comment: @TimWescott I had that same thought (output voltage has a max of input voltage if I'm thinking straight). I can get that data, and I may do it anyway, but if the question is going to be closed, I need not do it right away. Of course, complicating things is that the voltage is coming from a solar panel, so to get consistent results, I'd have to do the measurements on a clear day. BTW, the question is not so much about getting the two to work together but why the output voltage drops when the pot is rotated clockwise.

Comment: @CharlesCowie where can I find information on what questions are appropriate here? All I've been able to find is "Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts." I did not find anything stating it must be electrical engineering design or theory. I don't often dabble in EE, so please excuse my ignorance. Maybe you can suggest a better place to post my question?

Comment: Most of the information about asking questions is at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour. Knowing something of the design and theory of technical products is helpful for using them, so you are getting some comments here that may be helpful. Since there is not much hope of a definitive answer, you may get only comments and the question may be closed. I don't know if there is a better place to try.

Comment: I'm familiar with Stack Exchange. I've just not used this one. Your link is where I got that quote. It doesn't really go into detail about what is appropriate here. Since you implied my post was not appropriate, I thought maybe there was some document that explained what is relevant in more detail. Or maybe you weren't suggesting it was inappropriate, just that an answer is not likely.

Comment: It appears your power source cannot supply enough energy to keep the fan operating properly. I base this on the assumption the speed controller is operating properly and as you increase the fan speed it draws more current. As it requires more energy the source cannot supply it, it sacrifices something, in your case I believe it is the voltage which will cause the current to fold back and the fan to slow down.

Comment: But without the speed controller, it does just fine. In fact, as I posted originally, it blows a bit harder than I'd like. It's as if the speed controller is somehow using most of the power when the pot is dialed up. I thought with the pot dialed up to max, it should effectively be comparable to bypassing the controller.

Comment: @Victor Engel: I think the question is borderline rather than inappropriate. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. If there was a way to find out more details about the design of the products, I think the question would be fine.

Comment: There's a small window of almost clear weather this afternoon. Forecast is for overcast, so this is probably all I'll be able to gather for now. With no controller, about 7.7V and 3.3 amps. With controller, the same when potted full. It's about 8.5V and 3.7 amps when potted half way. This data was gathered in a rush because of the impending clouds. In any case both voltage and current were higher with the controller set in the middle. I also got with a friend with an oscilloscope, and we verified the frequency was consistent over the range with pulse width changing as expected.

Comment: So voltage is at the lower end of the stated range of the controller. I thought it was going to be more in the range of 12 volts.

Comment: Looking at the weather forecast, any more data will require waiting more than a week.

Comment: Gathering data like this is hard when the weather is not completely clear. After my last post, I got input voltage as high as 16+ and output voltage over 10.

Comment: Got a good streak of clear weather, so here are the final readings in full sun: input 14.3v, output 9.6v, 3.6 A when at the fastest setting. When wired direct: 8.06v, 3.04 amps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It achieves maximum speed when the pot is about in the middle
> position. When I rotate it clockwise some more, the fan slows down...
> At maximum fan speed (at the time I took readings) input voltage was
> around 13V, and output voltage around 8V. If I rotated the pot
> clockwise from that position, input voltage and output voltage both
> decreased.

The solar panel limits the current the motor can draw. Current determines motor torque and the fan needs more torque to spin faster, so the panel limits how fast the motor can spin the fan. If you had connected the solar panel directly to the fan you should have gotten the same voltage and speed as you did with the PWM control full on.

But how could the motor speed be *higher* with the PWM control only half way up? At 50% PWM the motor is drawing current from the power supply only during the 50% 'on' portion of each PWM period. During the other 50% of the time the motor is generating the same current via the inductance of its windings, which is recirculated through it via the [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) in the controller. Therefore the motor current is double the average supply current. If the controller has sufficient bulk capacitance on its input the solar panel only has to deliver (close to) the 50% lower average current.

This is balanced out by the average voltage across the motor being only half the supply voltage. So the power is the same, but the motor is getting lower voltage at higher current. In effect the PWM controller is 'transforming' the voltage and current like a buck-mode DC/DC converter does, using the motor windings at its inductance.

Solar panel output voltage drops slowly as current increases until it gets close to the current limit (determined by light intensity), then drops rapidly to zero if you try to draw more current. Maximum output power is obtained at the 'knee' of this curve. By adjusting the PWM control for maximum motor speed you have achieved the best match between solar panel output power and motor power consumption, which in a solar controller is called MPPT (Maximum Power Point Tracking).

> I'm also wondering why there was an audible noise when the pot was
> dialed mostly clockwise. Some sort of harmonic I suppose.

The motor commutation frequency may have been [beating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) with the PWM frequency to produce an audible difference frequency, the sound being produced by the PWM current pulses making the motor vibrate mechanically. This might only occur at high PWM ratio when the controller is unable to smooth out large changes in panel voltage when it is in current limit.

Comment: "If you had connected the motor directly to the fan you should have gotten the same voltage and speed as you did with the PWM control full on." Exactly what I was expected, but that is not what I was seeing. THAT is the essence of my question. Why does it go slower at full on than at half on? Edit: it is not just slower than at half-on. It is slower than with bypassing the controller completely - by a significant margin.

Comment: Sorry that should been 'solar panel directly to the fan'. If it is significantly slower through the controller when full on compared to a direct connection then the controller may not like operating with a current-limited input. Measure voltage at input and output of the controller with the pot fully clockwise. What do you get? What do you get with the solar panel connected directly to the fan?

Comment: Also, can you measure the resistance of the fan with your multimeter, with the probes in both directions? (should be approximately equal resistance with either polarity)

Comment: Resistance was 2.3 - 3.0 both ways. If I manually rotated the fan blades, the numbers would change slightly.

Comment: Hahah - I didn't even notice you said motor to fan. I read that as solar panel to fan, as you intended. :)

Comment: I think I'm going to accept this answer. I thought the controller was reducing the speed when potted all the way up, but after my latest test, it seems that it's boosting it when potted part way (same result when potted full).